# How to use select option value

Tags: php, mysql, select

Im trying to figure out how I can use both standard select option value together with a while loop select option value from mysql database. Right now I have this but won´t work any suggestions?

```
 <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="<?php echo $row_list['name'] ;?>"><?php echo $row_list['name'];?></option>
```

Comment: Maybe show a little more code.. this is not enough to help you.

Comment: This should work fine. Are you sure you have some values inside $row_list array?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ...>
    <option value="standard">...</option>
<?php while(...) { output more options here } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for this I solved it :D I just had to put the while loop before the other option value like you showed me.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 <?php 

    $cars=array("Mercedes", "Audi");//Let's have simple arrray with two objects
    ?>
    <select>
      <option value="All"> All</option>
      foreach($cars as $car){//Let's iterate through array elements
?>


 <option value="<?php echo $car;?>"> <?php echo $car;?> </option>
  <?php 
  }
?>
</select>
```